# IronPython cdll Cannot load library. Works if not using IronPython

Tags: python, dll, ironpython

I have a python script that loads a 'c' dll and it works fine when using python 2.7 (Anaconda). Here is a test script that I used to test the error:

```
import os
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath("a_c_library.dll"))
```

This works fine when using executing with python 2.7:
`python test.py`. No errors appear and I can also use the library afterwards.

If I use IronPython in my C# program or even just with a command line like so: 
`"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" test.py` or with ipy32.exe, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 445, in LoadLibrary
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
OSError: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.OSException: cannot load library **THE ABSOLUTE PATH TO MY DLL WHICH IS CORRECT**
```

Why can't I load the library when using IronPython? I'm on Windows 10. Again, I'm able to use the library when using normal python, but IronPython gives me an error with the same code.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: I tried to load that same dll directly from C# with that code:

```
[DllImport("a_c_library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "AFunction")]
static extern IntPtr Unmanged_AFunction();
```

And then calling the unmanged function and I get the following error: `System.BadImageFormatException: 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.` Tried with both x86 and x64 build. x64 gives this error instead: `System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'a_c_library.dll': The specified module could not be found.` even with the dll copied at the same location as the x64 exe.

Comment: What happens if you try to load the same DLL from C#? I don't know much about how IronPython's `ctypes` works under the hood, but I wouldn't be _that_ surprised if you there's some .NET error information that's being obscured here.

Comment: Hi, this error appears in C# when trying to call an unmanged function that I know exists in the dll and tested in python: `System.BadImageFormatException: 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.` Which is why I wanted to use python to use that dll instead of simply using it in c#.

Comment: Again, I haven't looked at how it works under the hood, but I'd be very, very surprised if the `ctypes` implementation in IronPython was anything but a wrapper around the same kind of native code interop (or whatever the .NET feature is called) that's already available to C#. So I can't see how switching to Python could possibly help here; what you're seeing is pretty much exactly what I'd expect you to see.

Comment: Also, please edit that information about calling from C# (and why you wanted to use IronPython—and, ideally, the actual C# code you tried) into your question. Even if I'm wrong, when one of the .NET or IronPython experts comes along, they'll almost surely need to know that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't load this library from C#, it's hard to imagine how IronPython would be any different; it can't be doing anything but wrapping up the same .NET APIs.

And if you look at [the source](https://github.com/jdhardy/ironpython-only/blob/master/Src/IronPython.Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.cs#L192), what `LoadLibrary` does is:

```
IntPtr res = NativeFunctions.LoadDLL(library, mode);
```

… and if it fails, you just get less error information:

```
throw PythonOps.OSError("cannot load library {0}", library);
```

As for that [`NativeFunctions.LoadDLL`](https://github.com/jdhardy/ironpython-only/blob/master/Src/IronPython.Modules/_ctypes/NativeFunctions.cs#L62), it's just a bit of wrapper code to decide whether to call `dlopen` out of `libdl.so` (on macOS and Linux), or to call [`LoadLibrary` out of `kernel32`](https://github.com/jdhardy/ironpython-only/blob/master/Src/IronPython.Modules/_ctypes/NativeFunctions.cs#L40) (otherwise).

So, if calling the native Windows function `LoadLibrary` doesn't work in C#, using `ctypes` is going to fail in exactly the same way, but then return you a less useful error message: instead of telling you (as mentioned in a comment) `System.BadImageFormatException: 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format'`, it just tells you `cannot load library`.

Comment: Thank you for the informations and making me understand better why it doesn't work. So the problem is that when ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary is called it is loading it out of kernel32 (the C# way)? I'm not sure how does python usually load foreign libraries. Do you think there's a way to make IronPython load the dll like python (Anaconda) would do (since it works if not using IronPython) but retain the other features of IronPython like the C# types and being able to call python functions from C#?

Comment: @Mick412 The CPython interpreter is native code; IronPython is managed code that runs inside of .NET. So, the CPython version of `ctypes` just calls `LoadLibrary` out of `kernel32` directly; IronPython does the closest thing it can to that, which is declaring it as a native-interop call and trying to call it, but if .NET doesn't like what you're doing, .NET will stop you. In particular, if you try to load a library that can't be loaded into the .NET runtime, it's going to fail.

Comment: @Mick412 One thing to rule out really quickly: If you're using a 32-bit CPython in Anaconda, and a 32-bit DLL, but on a 64-bit OS with 64-bit .NET and IronPython, that could actually be the reason both C# and IronPython are failing to load the library, and that's something you can deal with.

Comment: I think I found the problem because of what you said. The dll I'm trying to use is 64 bit I think. I tried using that same script with miniconda 32 bit and got `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`. Now I just have to find what dependency is missing when trying to load the dll in .NET I think because the error it gives me is `System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'edk.dll': The specified module could not be found. ` Thank you!

Comment: @Mick412 Great! That’s a lot easier to deal with.